# AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) Indexed PDF Search Results

Tags: pdf, search, indexing, adobe, aem

My employer has recently switched its CMS to AEM(Adobe Experience Manager).
We store a large amount of documentation and our site users need to be able to find the information contained within those documents, some of which are 100s pages in length.

Adobe are disappointingly saying their search tool will not search PDFs. Is there any format for producing or saving pdfs that allow the content be indexed?

Comment: Maybe you should for a more robust search engine, like Apache Solr to do give you the indexing and search capabilities for the PDFs stored in the AEM DAM.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure external index/search tools like Apache Solr and use REST endpoint to sync DAM data and fetch results on queries.

Comment: Hi Rajat, thank you for your reply. 
Yes it appears the solution is to use SOLR or TIKA

Comment: AEM has Tika built it and it uses it to process PDF's... so just upload your docs into AEM and you will be fine. You can enable Solr, AEM has this OOTB and AEM will still extract data using Tika and send it to Solr...

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box AEM supports most binary formats, without needing for SOLR. You only need this in advanced scenarios, like exposing search outside of Authoring or having millions of assets.

When any asset is uploaded to AEM Dam it will go though a Dam Asset Workflow which has a step Metadata Processor. That step will extract content from the asset. So "binary" assets like Word docs, Excel and PDF it will be searchable. As long as you have Dam Asset Update workflow enabled you will be ok.

[image]